# PHP Add Day or 24 Hours

Tags: php, yii

I have an app that allows user to put in a start time and end time. If the end time is into the next day I need to adjust the date. There are currently three input fields, date, battery_start and battery_end.

The battery times are in 24 hour format without the :, i.e. Hm. I am checking to see if the calculation ends up being less than 0, battery_total < 0, and if so I want to set the battery_end to the next day, but with the time the user entered into the field.

```
     /**
     * if the flight spans two days, i.e. starts late at night
     * and ends early in the morning then adjust datetime
     */
    public function adjustFlightTime()
    {
        //check battery times
        if($this->battery_total < 0)
        {
            $this->battery_end = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime("$this->battery_end +1 days"));
            $this->battery_total = $this->battery_total +24;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try and save the new battery_end time I get an additional 9 minutes added to the time, the date is correct.

DJ

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($this->battery_end);
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$this->battery_total = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Note that I've also changed `m` to `i`.

Comment: +1 for the sound advice. Never reinvent the wheel when there is a class that does the job for you. Doubly so when the class is native to the framework you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

You must write `Y-m-d H:i:s`, not `Y-m-d H:m:s`

m = month